# How to clean the postgres instance while setting cartoDB locally in ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, carto

I am following https://github.com/danseely/cartodb-install/blob/master/DEV-INSTALLATION.md for setting cartoDB locally in ubuntu12.04.

While installing cartoDB-postgresql, the second install check of cartoDB-postgresql fails in test_ddl_triggers and also in CDB_quota_test.

It is mentioned to change the shared_preload_libraries = 'schema_triggers.so' in postgresql.conf if test_ddl_triggers and restart the postgres by service postgresql restart but still the error remains same after making changes and restarting.

It is also given to clean postgres instances in https://github.com/cartodb/cartodb-postgresql/ to test installation.

How to clean the instances and test the installation for error free?